# Got this error "[Errno 13] Permission denied" while I'm trying to convert the image into string and store that in file

Tags: python, image, file

Here is the code I tried:

```
import base64
with open("D:/Pic's/pic/Wallpapers/ww/gaming/1 (20).jpg","rb") 
as image2string:
converted_string = base64.b64encode(image2string.read())
print(converted_string)
```

Image successfully converted to string in (converted_string)

Now I'm trying to save it in file:

```
with open("C:/Users/a/Desktop/img","wb") as file:
file.write(converted_string)
```

Got this error:
`[Errno 13] Permission denied`
I checked the file and tried to give the permissions but couldn't find out the way

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Seems like you are writing into a folder?

Comment: yes, my final goal is to save the image in postgres db

Comment: You will get the exception `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` if `"C:/Users/a/Desktop/img"` exist as a folder, not a filename.